# BeautifulSoap get multiple element for all img in a div with specific class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the links in `image-file` attribute (relative link as it is) in `img` tags under `div` with `id` `previewImages` (I don't want the `src` link).

Here is the sample HTML:

```
<div id="previewImages">
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/15.jpg" image-file="/image/15.jpg" /></a> </div>
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/2.jpg" image-file="/image/2.jpg" /> </a> </div>
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/0.jpg" image-file="/image/0.jpg" /> </a> </div>
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/3.jpg" image-file="/image/3.jpg" /> </a> </div>
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/4.jpg" image-file="/image/4.jpg" /> </a> </div>
</div>
```

I tried the following but it only gives me the first link and not all:

```
import sys
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page = sys.argv[1] # this should be the first argument on the command line
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

images_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'previewImages'})
if images_box.find('img'):
    imagesurl = images_box.find('img').get('image-file')
print imagesurl
```

How can I get all the links in `image-file` attritube for `img` tags in `div` with `class previewImages`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.findAll`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div id="previewImages">
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/15.jpg" image-file="/image/15.jpg" /></a> </div>
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/2.jpg" image-file="/image/2.jpg" /> </a> </div>
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/0.jpg" image-file="/image/0.jpg" /> </a> </div>
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/3.jpg" image-file="/image/3.jpg" /> </a> </div>
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/4.jpg" image-file="/image/4.jpg" /> </a> </div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
images_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'previewImages'})
for link in images_box.findAll("img"):
    print link.get('image-file')
```

**Output:**

```
/image/15.jpg
/image/2.jpg
/image/0.jpg
/image/3.jpg
/image/4.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it faster to use id with attribute selector passed to `select`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = '''
<div id="previewImages">
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/15.jpg" image-file="/image/15.jpg" /></a> </div>
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/2.jpg" image-file="/image/2.jpg" /> </a> </div>
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/0.jpg" image-file="/image/0.jpg" /> </a> </div>
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/3.jpg" image-file="/image/3.jpg" /> </a> </div>
  <div class="thumb"> <a><img src="https://example.com/s/4.jpg" image-file="/image/4.jpg" /> </a> </div>
</div>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
links = [item['image-file'] for item in soup.select('#previewImages [image-file]')]
print(links)
```

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup has method `.find_all()` - check the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all). This is how you can use it in your code:

```
import sys
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page = sys.argv[1] # this should be the first argument on the command line
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

images_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'previewImages'})
links = [img['image-file'] for img in images_box('img')]

print links   # in Python 3: print(links)
```

Answer (score 0):

To Add up if in case we have do the same scenario with lxml,

```
import lxml.html
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(sample)
images = tree.xpath("//img/@image-file")
print(images)
```

Output
['/image/15.jpg', '/image/2.jpg', '/image/0.jpg', '/image/3.jpg', '/image/4.jpg']